# Blur the background When Click Drop Down Menu Appear

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to have the entire background page is blur when click on a button and drop down appear, but some how the blur background didn't show up.

Please give me a hand.

This is HTML

```
<div class="click-nav">
  <ul class="no-js">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="clicker"><img src="img/i-1.png" alt="Icon">Profile</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/i-2.png" alt="Icon">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/i-3.png" alt="Icon">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/i-4.png" alt="Icon">Privacy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/i-5.png" alt="Icon">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/i-6.png" alt="Icon">Sign out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is CSS

```
 body {background-color:#334873}
.click-nav {margin:100px auto;width:200px;}
.click-nav ul {position:relative;font-weight:900;}
.click-nav ul li {position:relative;list-style:none;cursor:pointer;}
.click-nav ul li ul {position:absolute;left:0;right:0;}
.click-nav ul .clicker {position:relative;background:#2284B5;color:#FFF;}
.click-nav ul .clicker:hover,.click-nav ul .active {background:#196F9A;}
.click-nav img {position:absolute;top:9px;left:12px;}
.click-nav ul li a {transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;-webkit-transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;display:block;padding:8px 10px 8px 40px;background:#FFF;color:#333;text-decoration:none;}
.click-nav ul li a:hover {background:#F2F2F2;}

/* Fallbacks */
.click-nav .no-js ul {display:none;}
.click-nav .no-js:hover ul {display:block;}

.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    display:none; 

    /* color with alpha transparency */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

    /* stretch to screen edges */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

and this is JS

```
$(function () {
  $('.click-nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
  $('.click-nav .js ul').hide();
  $('.click-nav .js').click(function(e) {
    $('.click-nav .js ul').slideToggle(200);
    $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    if ($('.click-nav .js ul').is(':visible')) {
      $('.click-nav .js ul', this).slideUp();
      $('.clicker').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
  $('.click-nav').click(
            function()
            {
                $('body').addClass('overlay');
            }
        );
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this **[Updated Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4n2R/1/)**

JS:

```
$('.clicker').click(function () {
    $('body').toggleClass('overlay');
});
```

CSS :

```
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    /* color with alpha transparency */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    /* stretch to screen edges */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

- The class `click-nav` is the parent `<div>` and not the button.
- Remove `display:none` from `.overlay` css.