# How to show gray background when dropdown-menu button is clicked?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have simple dropdown-menu and few items on it, like example here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#single-button

How to disable background (display gray area) once I clicked on dropdown button, like it is displayed when I call modal?

Thank you.

Comment: according to what you've asked this can be your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177046/blur-the-background-when-click-drop-down-menu-appear

Answer (score -1):

Actually, this is what I searched for: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/ZXxpl
Thanks.